# When taking the square root of an adjoined element in a finite field, are both roots available?

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory

Suppose I have the finite field $\mathbb{F}_8$ and I want to adjoin a number of order 8, $\zeta$, and consider the field extension $\mathbb{F}_8(\zeta)$. Then $\zeta^8 \equiv 1 \mod 8$ and so $\zeta^{8} - 1 \equiv (\zeta^4 - 1)(\zeta^4 + 1) \equiv 0 \mod 8$ Then $\zeta^4 \equiv 1 \mod p$ and $\zeta^4 \equiv -1 \mod p$ are both solutions.

So when performing arithmetic in the field extension, such as factoring polynomials, can I choose whichever root is convenient for what I want to show? Here's an example of what I mean:

If I can pick and choose if $\zeta^4$ is $\pm1$, then I can say that, modulo 8, $(1 - \zeta^4)(1 + \zeta^4) = 1 - \zeta^4 + \zeta^4 - \zeta^8 = 1 + 1 + 1 - 1 = 2$.

But then I could also say that, modulo 8, $(1 - \zeta^4)(1 + \zeta^4) = 1 - \zeta^4 + \zeta^4 - \zeta^8 = 1 - 1 + 1 - 1 = 0$.

This appears contradictory, so I'm assuming that either $\zeta^4 \equiv 1 \mod 8$ OR $\zeta^4 \equiv -1 \mod 8$, but not both simultaneously.

But then how do I know which one it is if I want to make use of $\zeta^4$?

Comment: The field of order $8$ has characteristic $2$, so $+1=-1$ in this field.

Comment: I know that you are correct, but I still don't understand why the characteristic of $\mathbb{F}_{8}$ is 2. Why wouldn't it be 8? The characteristic of a field is the smallest positive number $n$ such that $1 + \cdots + 1 = 0$. It would seem to me that $8 \equiv 0 \mod 8$ but $2 \not\equiv 0 \mod 8$.

Comment: You seem to think that $\mathbb F_8$ is $\mathbb Z/8$.  It isn't.  $\mathbb Z/8$ is not a field, not even an integral domain, because in it $4\cdot 2=0$ while $4\neq0$ and $2\neq 0$.

Comment: Thank you, I completely overlooked that. So what about a general finite field $\mathbb{F}_p$ where we don't know the characteristic? In that case, how would we know what $\zeta^4$ is. Am I allowed to choose as long as I am consistent with my choice?

Comment: In general, there will be several $8$-th roots of $1$, and you can consider any of them, but your choice may be constrained by what you want to do with them. Some of these $8$-th roots of 1 will already be in your starting field, for example $1$ and $-1$, and possibly others.  You don't want those if you want your $\zeta$ to generate a bigger field. Note that it can happen that *all* roots of $\zeta^8$ are already in $\mathbb F_p$, for example if $p=17$.

Comment: I see, thank you. Now in a proof, again with unknown $p$ and adjoining $\zeta$ or order 8, am I allowed to say that $\zeta^4 \equiv 1 (p)$ and $\zeta^4 \equiv -1 (p)$ and swap between the two mid-proof?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14041/discussion-between-user2521987-and-andreas-blass)

Answer (score 1):

Before you make any computation with the root you have to decide exactly which root is. You can teke the example to a (hopefully) more familiar set of numbers: $\Bbb Q$. When you adjoin a root $\alpha$ of the polynomial $X^2-2$ you have to decide between $\alpha=\sqrt 2$ and $\alpha=-\sqrt 2$. If you toggle your decision inside a single computation (as you did before) you can end up with funny identities like
$$\sqrt 2+\sqrt 2=0$$
that would have upset poor Pythagoras even more...

Comment: So when writing a proof involving $\zeta^4$, would the correct thing to say be: "Since $\zeta^8 \equiv \mod 8$ implies that $(\zeta^4 - 1)(\zeta^4 + 1) \equiv 0 \mod 8$, either $\zeta^4 \equiv 1 \mod 8$ or $\zeta^4 \equiv -1 \mod 8$. So let $\zeta^4 \equiv -1 \mod 8$. Then..."?

Answer (score 1):

If $F$ is any field and contains *one* solution $a$ of a quadratic equation $X^2+pX+q=0$, then it also contains the other - because the other solution is simply $-p-a$. (In your case, that is in characteristic $2$ and with $p=0$, however, the "other" is just $a$ again).

Comment: So when writing a proof and considering a general finite field $\mathbb{F}_p$, how would I notate that if I want to make use of one of those roots? In my example, I would like to make use of the fact that $\zeta^4 \equiv 1 \mod 4$. But perhaps later in the proof, I may want to use the fact that $\zeta^4 \equiv -1 \mod 4$.